# Restore deleted web app from Microsoft azure

Tags: azure

dears all 
could you help me from argent issues talked about
How i can restore web app service from resource group in Microsoft azure ?
and i never back up active

Comment: File a support case with Microsoft Support. They may be able to help you restore it. No means to do it yourself if you don't have a backup.

Comment: It seems that you cannot restore it if you deleted it by yourself.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately there's no way to recover a deleted Web App (sure, you can contact support, but I wouldn't count on them being able to recover what you had). Just curious, how did you deploy your web app? Typically it's through a source control provider such as github. Or, possibly via Visual Studio. Did you destroy all source that you used for deployment? One last note: Stack Overflow really isn't the place for something like this (or for "urgent" matters); this really isn't on-topic (not programming related).

Answer (score 2):

Azure has included support in CLI and PowerShell to recover deleted web apps:

https://medium.com/@krrajapakse91/omg-deleted-my-web-app-and-app-service-plan-whats-next-ba39728bff15

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/restore-azureaddeletedapplication?view=azureadps-2.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-restore

Comment: This explains how to restore a site using Az PowerShell commands: https://ruslany.net/2019/06/how-to-restore-a-deleted-azure-web-app/